# Could not render correct predicted coordinate of an image using cv2

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, opencv, python

I am fine-tuning VGG-16 for face-detection and the input shape = (120,120,3). When I predict it in test set and plot the coordinate, everything looks correct. But when I perform some real time detection, the coordinate couldn't be render correctly.

Here, I plot the predicted coordinates of batch of test-set.

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(ncols=4,nrows=4,figsize=(60,60))

for idx,ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):

  img = test_X[idx].copy()

  cv2.rectangle(img,
          tuple(np.multiply(coords[idx][:2], [120,120]).astype(int)),
          tuple(np.multiply(coords[idx][2:],[120,120]).astype(int)),
         (255,0,0),1)
  ax.imshow(img)

  plt.tight_layout()
```

Output:
[Predicted Coordinates of Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5lwM.jpg)

This is where I try doing Real-time detection:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
  _ , frame = cap.read()

  frame = cv2.resize(frame,(640,380))

  rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  resized = tf.image.resize(rgb, (120,120))

  classes,coords = facetracker.predict(np.expand_dims(resized/255.0,0))

  if classes > 0.5: 
    # Controls the main rectangle
    cv2.rectangle(frame, 
                  tuple(np.multiply(coords[0][:2], [640,380]).astype(int)),
                  tuple(np.multiply(coords[0][2:], [640,380]).astype(int)), 
                        (255,0,0), 2)
    

  cv2.imshow('EyeTrack', frame)

  if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
    
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output: [Screenshot of real-time prediction](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L_JlbEN7dowKxNEp9nuuiTluFsf5AOSy/view?usp=share_link)

Answer (score 0):

You're not rescaling your bounding boxes correctly, it should be `a = np.multiply(coords[0][:2], [120,120]`, this part let's you go from normalized to pixel scale then `np.multiply(a, [640/120,380/120]` this rescales your bounding boxes from 120X120 to your frame size.